# zoomin/zoomout of an image in html5

Tags: html

i have simple application which should work on keyboard events like onfocus and onblur instead of onmouseover and onmouseout.

here is my code snippet to zoomin/zoomout:

```
<script>
   var nW,nH,oH,oW;
   function zoom(iWideSmall,iHighSmall,iWideLarge,iHighLarge,whichImage)
   {
    oW=whichImage.style.width;oH=whichImage.style.height;
    if((oW==iWideLarge)||(oH==iHighLarge))
    {
     nW=iWideSmall;nH=iHighSmall;
    }
    else
    {
     nW=iWideLarge;nH=iHighLarge;
    }
    whichImage.style.width=nW;whichImage.style.height=nH;
   }
  </script>
```

calling this function in this way:

```
<td align=center valign=middle >

    <figure>
        <button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none"><img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png" onfocus="zoom('57px','120px','96px','136px',this);"
onblur="zoom('57px','120px','57px','120px',this);" > </button>
     <figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font></figcaption>
    </figure>

   </td>
```

but problem is when i select image using tab key i cant see any zoomin/zoomout effect. if i replace onfocus/onblur with onmouseover/onmouseout respectively it works well.

please some one help me where i am going wrong.

regards
rashmi

Answer (score 0):

You will not get focus on an img element by tabbing but on the button element instead. Move your onblur/onfocus events to the button element. This will change your button's size each time you focus/lose focus on it, but it will not change your image size. What you have to do then is to modify your code so the change is mapped on the button's contained image dimensions as well. Something that I can think of right now is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var nW,nH,oH,oW;
   function zoom(iWideSmall,iHighSmall,iWideLarge,iHighLarge,whichElement)
   {

    theImage = whichElement.firstChild;
    theImage.style.width=nW;theImage.style.height=nH;
    oW=whichElement.style.width;oH=whichElement.style.height;
    if((oW==iWideLarge)||(oH==iHighLarge))
    {
     nW=iWideSmall;nH=iHighSmall;
    }
    else
    {
     nW=iWideLarge;nH=iHighLarge;
    }
    whichElement.style.width=nW;whichElement.style.height=nH;
    theImage.style.width=nW;theImage.style.height=hH;
   }
</script>
```

Here, the first child of the button element, which happens to be the image, takes the same height and width with the button, whenever that changes.

Comment: thanks rabbitisle, i got your point but dont know how would i work on it as i am newbie......:(

Comment: you can ping me on my email-id rashufatty@gmail.com

Comment: I've added some code, hope it helps. It will probably need some testing from you.

Comment: i tried adding this code you know rabbitisle doing so wont zoomin/zoomout even with onmouseover/onmouseout property

Comment: Did you set the onfocus/onblur events on the button, instead of the img? I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: yes i have set onfocus/onblur events on button. this is following code:  <td align=center valign=middle >
<figure>
<button style="background-color:black; border:none; width:160px; height:160px; outline-color:white;" onfocus="zoom('57px','120px','96px','136px',this);"
onblur="zoom('57px','120px','57px','120px',this);"><img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png"  > </button>
<figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font></figcaption>
</figure>
</td> and zoom function is same as one you have posted